# Excel sumif date range does not contain weekday

Tags: excel, sumifs

I'm trying to create a formula that would allow me to figure out the value of booking within a month if it is for weekdays but doesn't overlap the weekend. So a guest may check in on a Tuesday and check out on a Friday and this would equate to "True" and the value of the booking would be counted as a weekday. So sum a range if a start date does not contain a Friday or Saturday, end date does not contain a Saturday or Sunday, and the date range does not contains/overlaps both a Saturday and Sunday.

**G1=5/1/2022**

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **start** | **end** | **value** | **house** | **weekday?** |
| **2** | 5/9/2022 | 5/13/2022 | 250 | house 1 | true |
| **3** | 5/19/2022 | 5/21/2022 | 225 | house 1 | false |
| **4** | 5/29/2022 | 6/1/2022 | 175 | house 1 | true |
| **5** | 5/24/2022 | 6/1/2022 | 150 | house 2 | false |

=SUMIFS(C2:C4,A2:A5,">="&G1,C2:C4, "<="&EOMONTH(G1,0),D2:D5,"house 1", this is the part where I need to determine if the date range contains a start on a friday or saturday, ends on saturday or sunday, or the range contains both a friday and a saturday)

The end result would be that both A2 and A4 would be true and equate to A2+A4 = 250 + 150 = 400

Basically I am using historic booking data to forecast potential future revenue by looking what bookings per month were, breaking them down by if the booking contained a weekend or was just weekdays, and then looking at remaining open weekdays in the year and projecting potential revenue by what average number of dates were that were booked in low season and high season. This above is just step 1 in a much larger equation.

Comment: Basically need to take start date and if true (is weekday - sun through thurs) iterate till I reach the end date and true or a false (is weekend - sat). Can excel iterate within a formula? If I have to move to a vba function I would probably just jump to google sheets as I'm much more comfortable with JS than vba.

Comment: Improve the question instead of adding information in comments. You could check out the weekday series of functions.

Comment: Question: you say the startdate cannot be a Friday, why? In `row 3` you have a booking that starts and ends on the same day. This happens to be a Thursday, but if it was a Friday, you would want to count it as a weekday, no?

Comment: [How frequent StackOverFlow contributors view most new posts...](https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vSdMLWFeC6kiyc0VbMao8wFL5bm_--tMin5IXCQSJTyjV6j5riQ2by3cPMI86K0q4JqqjQAjsmA4WKP/pub)

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: @oruoboros, you caught an error on my end. Corrected.

Comment: @Ron Ronsfield, office 16

Answer (score 0):

If you put this function in E2 and drag it down, I think it populates properly with `True`/`False` values (note I previously overlooked the potential same-day checkout.

```
=AND(WEEKDAY(A2,1)<6,WEEKDAY(B2,2)<6,WEEKDAY(B2,1)>=WEEKDAY(A2,1),B2-A2<5)
```

Here's a dynamic spill version of the formula that updates as the column gets more data.

```
=FILTER(((WEEKDAY(A:A,1)<6)*(WEEKDAY(B:B,2)<6)*(WEEKDAY(B:B,1)>=WEEKDAY(A:A,1))*(B:B-A:A<5))=1,(A:A>0)*(ROW(A:A)>1))
```

I think it covers all possibilities. I threw in some more dates for testing....

[image]

Comment: Modified answer to account for same-day arrival/departure.

Answer (score 0):

I put your data in a **Table** which I named `Bookings`.

Given the apparent change in your requirements as pointed out to me by @pgSystemTester:

The formula for the **weekday?** column would then be:

```
=AND(WEEKDAY([@start],17)<6,WEEKDAY(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,[@start]+1):INDEX($A:$A,[@end])),2)<6)
```

[image]

and the total:

```
=SUMIF(Bookings[Weekday?],TRUE,Bookings[value])
```

Comment: The post changed slightly so this wouldn't work for a Sunday to Wednesday date (I had the same issue previously).